# SQL - Joining one table with another based on ( Row value from first table to Column value of second table)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have two tables which looks as below

First table :

```
   DealNum      CurrencyValue      CurrencyCode       Date

    110             100                 AA         01/12/2011  
    111             200                 AB         01/11/2011
    112             120                 AC         01/10/2011  
    113             20                  AA         01/11/2011
    110             103                 AD         01/12/2011  
    115             200                 AD         01/11/2011
    119             120                 AG         01/10/2011  
    130             20                  AK         01/11/2011
```

Second Table

```
   CurrencyCode     OCT       NOV      DEC     JAN   ..

      AA             0.91     0.88     0.9     0.94  
      AB             0.9      0.8      0.96    0.89
      AC             0.81     0.79     0.82    0.84  
      AD             0.4      0.41     0.42    0.39
      AE             0.9      0.92     0.91    0.94  
      AF             0.8      0.82     0.83    0.81
```

now I want to add the data from the second table to first table in a new column with the following conditions

```
1.It has to do based on the CurrencyCode and month
2.If the deal is from DEC and currencyCode is AA , then it has to take the value 0.9,
  if the deal is from NOV and currencyCode is AA , then it has to take the value 0.88..
```

So, The result should look like this

```
   DealNum      CurrencyValue      CurrencyCode       Date        NewColumn

    110             100                 AA         01/12/2011        0.9
    111             200                 AB         01/11/2011        0.8
    112             120                 AC         01/10/2011        0.81  
    113             20                  AA         01/11/2011        0.88
    110             103                 AD         01/12/2011        0.42
    115             200                 AD         01/11/2011        0.41
    119             120                 AG         01/10/2011         --
    130             20                  AK         01/11/2011         --
```

I have no clue on how to do this with comparing row value of month from first table to column value of month in second table. Please help me with this..

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Harish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, although you second table is not designed well.

```
SELECT   DealNum      
       , CurrencyValue      
       , CurrencyCode       
       , Date
       , Deal = 
         CASE MONTH(t1.Date)
           WHEN 1 THEN t2.JAN
           WHEN 2 THEN t2.FEB
           WHEN 3 THEN t2.MAR
           -- .....
           WHEN 10 THEN t2.OCT
           WHEN 11 THEN t2.NOV
           WHEN 12 THEN t2.DEC
        END
FROM Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.CurrencyCode = t2.CurrencyCode
```

- [MONTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx)
- [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms181765.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Tim Schmelter.. this one is great.. working fine for me. But, the thing here is the column names(Months) in the second table keep on changing everytime, is there any dynamic way of doing this, like if the t1.date = t2.(XYZ month) then t2.Jan or t2.Feb??? Thanks again for your help :))